# PowerApp not storing All AD group members in Person type column

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have the following code which is used to get members of an AD group based on a condition. I have added comments for clarity.

```
If(GroupsField2.Selected.DisplayName = "ADGroup2", //GroupsField2 is a person-type field that selects an AD group

   ForAll(varADGroup2, // variable stores 2 users correctly, variable data shows 2 members
     {
        Claims:"c:0t.c|membership|"& userPrincipalName,
        Email:"",
        Department:"",
        DisplayName:"",
        JobTitle:"",
        Picture:""
      }
   )
)
```

These members need to be stored in a person type column (Allow selection of groups is enabled, allow multiple selections is enabled).
This group contains 2 members, but only 1 member is stored in the SharePoint list column.
Any idea if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates over varADGroup2, but according to the snippet, it never references the current value in the current iteration of the loop. It's hard to tell if this was intentional or not, so I am assuming userPrincipalName is a property of varADGroup2, and it needs to be accessed from the `ThisRecord` object that is available in the ForAll statement.

```
If(GroupsField2.Selected.DisplayName = "ADGroup2", //GroupsField2 is a person-type field that selects an AD group
   ForAll(varADGroup2, // variable stores 2 users correctly, variable data shows 2 members
     {
        Claims:"c:0t.c|membership|"& ThisRecord.userPrincipalName, // Updated
        Email:"",
        Department:"",
        DisplayName:"",
        JobTitle:"",
        Picture:""
      }
   )
)
```

Comment: I have managed to store all members correctly using the following code. But it is creating two rows with same ID. One row with the form data, and 2nd row with group members in the selected column.
It should patch/update the selected column in the last submitted row only. 

SubmitForm(Form1);
If(
    Form1.LastSubmit.GroupsField2.DisplayName = "ADGroup2",
Patch(Orders,
{
OrderID:FormAddNewPO.LastSubmit.OrderID,    
ADGroup2Members: 

ForAll(
    varADGroup2,
{Claims:"c:0t.c|membership|"& userPrincipalName,
Email:"",
Department:"",
DisplayName:"",
JobTitle:"",
Picture:""})}));